# error: failed to discover supported resources: Get http://localhost:8080/apis/apps/v1?

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and I am trying to create a pod but I am facing this error can someone help?

(base) Dishas-Air:config dishaaa$ kubectl create deployment nanopore --image=nginx

```
W1221 16:55:10.854937   48732 loader.go:223] Config not found: /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
W1221 16:55:10.887246   48732 loader.go:223] Config not found: /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
error: failed to discover supported resources: Get http://localhost:8080/apis/apps/v1?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

Comment: Seems you Kubernetes is not up and running.. what do you get when you run `kubectl get all` ?

Comment: I am getting this error:
W1221 17:33:30.497746   49041 loader.go:223] Config not found: /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
W1221 17:33:30.573830   49041 loader.go:223] Config not found: /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Comment: I guess.. Kubernetes is not installed correctly.. try to reinstall k8s

Comment: There is not much information that you provide. Having much more information about config and steps to reproduce will speed help to you questions. Please consult my answer and let me know if have any more issues.

Comment: Thank you so much, I resolved this issue as by using minikube start. There was some problem with connecting to the port initially and this command resolved it.

Comment: @DISHA98LODHA since my answer solved your issue would you consider accepting/uvpoting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your cluster was not initialized correctly or you did not went thru all the prerequisites config to make work appropriately or your cluster simply is not running.

The first step would be to check your (`~/.kube/config`) file and if it exist.
The `kubectl` command-line tool uses kubeconfig files to find the information it needs to choose a cluster and communicate with the API server of a cluster. By default,  it looks for a file named `config` in the `$HOME/.kube` directory.

Kubeadm once initialize  your control plane ask you to perform couple of commands in order to start using your cluster. This is need to make `kubectl` work for your non-root user:

```sh
Your Kubernetes control-plane has initialized successfully!
To start using your cluster, you need to run the following as a regular user:

  mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

The above information is place assuming you went all the steps up to `init`. If you have not please have a look at [creating kubeadm cluster document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/).

If you are using minikube please have look if you cluster is running by `minikube status`. If your Kubernetes cluster is not running please go thru [minikube get started](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) document.